# Запуск программ по названию

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Создал скрипт на PHP, сделал исполняемым, добавил директиву пути до самого PHP. Остался вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы я мог вызывать свою программу просто введя ее название? То есть не через `/path-to-script/my_script`, а просто введя название `my_script`.

И да, хотелось бы, чтобы можно было запускать программу не только из-под своего пользователя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя скрипт должен находится по одному из путей перечисленных в переменной $PATH

Answer (score 2):

Я обычно кидаю симлинку в sbin. Делается так:

```
ln -s /path-to-script/my_script /sbin/my_script
```